# What's the minimal directory structure to make setuptools work with one_file.py?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils

`one_file.py` contains some general functions, classes, and a `main()`.

I'd like to make it `pip` installable with a command line script that calls the `main()` function.

What's a directory structure and `setup.py` that will do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get away with this with just a `setup.py` and your module--no additional directories.  In your `setup.py` just use `setup(..., py_modules=['one_file'], ...)`  (you might want to check on the exact spelling).  To install the script you can use the `console_scripts` entry-point:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='one-file',
    version='1.0',
    py_modules=['one_file'],
    entry_points={'console_scripts': ['one-file = one_file:main']}
)
```

Comment: One fine point, I like to do `from setuptools import find_packages` and then pass `packages=find_packages()` instead of hardcoding `py_modules=...` inside the call to `setup(...)`.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston The original question, although poorly worded, was about distributing single modules that are not in a package.  `find_packages()` explicitly just returns packages.

Comment: Good point.  This question is at the top of the first page for a Google query of "python minimal setup.py".  Admittedly I missed that part of OP's question, but this answer was also helpful for a quick reference of the minimal setup.py for a one file package as well.

Comment: Wow, that's too bad that this is one of the first things that comes up.