# Do I need an __init__.py if I want to build a standalone program and not a package?

Tags: python, software-distribution

I am working on a standalone Python-GUI-program. When I run

```
python3 setup.py sdist
```

I get the following warning:

```
package init file 'main-application-folder/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
```

Is this warning only meant for packages or should a standalone Python program also have an `__init__.py` instead of something like `main-window.py` or `my-first-program.py`?

Should I rename my main file (in my case `ìbk-st.py` to `__init__.py`) or would it be good to retain a certain structure in the `__init__.py` (i.e. make a separate file that calls the `ibk-st.py` file)

Link to project:

- https://github.com/tobias47n9e/innsbruck-stereographic

Comment: It's not clear what distinction you're drawing between *"packages"* and a *"standalone Python program"* - packages generally *are* standalone programs. You have numerous `.py` files grouped together in a directory, so yes you should write an `__init__.py` to specify what should be exposed publicly from them.

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444747/whats-the-minimal-directory-structure-to-make-setuptools-work-with-one-file-py/28573255#28573255

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Sorry to be so easily confused but does that mean I should rename my ibk-st.py to `__init__.py` or are there certain specifications that an `__init__.py` should fulfil?

Comment: @Spießbürger I suppose you *could*, but that would be unconventional - `__init__.py` usually contains very little code, just imports of the names you want to expose externally. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/448271/3001761

Comment: you have packages = ["ibk-st"] in your setup.py, so naturally distutils ask for a __init__.py in the package. If you don't want to distribute a package just use only py-modules.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: That clears up my confusion a lot. I would accept it, if you post it as an answer.

Comment: @mkiever: Is that a mistake? I just started experimenting with packaging a few days ago. So I am still not sure what best practices are.

Comment: @mkiever: Thank you i will read up on the `packages = ` option!

Comment: @Spießbürger: Take a look at the Simple Example in the Introduction of distutils documentation for an example without packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rename the `ibk-st` into a valid package identifier for python (`ibk_st` maybe); then `ibk-st.py` into something like `main_ui.py`; then have an `__init__.py` for that whole package (alternatively you can rename `ibk-st.py` to `__init__.py`).

Do note that [`setup.py` can install command line scripts](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts); you can provide a thin wrapper as file `bin/ibk-st-ui` with contents

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ibk_st.main_ui import main
main()
```

The module installation will ensure that the script is runnable on whatever platform the user is using.

Then in your `setup.py` you should have

```
...
packages = [ 'ibk_st' ],
scripts=[ 'bin/ibk-st-ui' ],
...
```

Now when you run the `setup.py install` or install the package, the modules can be embedded into other programs **and** the command `ibk-st-ui` will be installed in the the `bin` folder (be it the `bin` of a virtualenv or the system `/usr/local/bin`), that can run the UI.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. I will reed up on those details and get my project structure in order!