# Did I organise my Python directory incorrectly?

Tags: python, directory-structure, nose

I am trying to make a stand-alone application in Python and there are some problems related to imports and the project's directory structure that I do not how to solve.

This is how the project is structured:

```
root/
  app/
    __init__.py 
    main.py
    foo.py     
  tests/
    __init__.py
    main_tests.py
    foo_tests.py
```

These are the two conflicting requirements which I don't know how to solve:

- The tests are written using the Nose framework. When I run `nosetests` from the `root` directory, it requires all imports to be relative to the `app` package.

  ```
  # app/main.py
  import app.foo  # `import foo` will not work
  ```
- On the other hand, if I want to *run* the application from `root` (with a command like `python app/main.py`), another problem occurs. It will rightly complain that it cannot find the `app` package.

How can I fix these problems? Is there anything I need to change in how I organized my project?

Comment: I would expect imports in `tests` to have to be absolute, but not `app`. It sounds like this is a problem of properly setting up the python path used by the testing framework.

Comment: @aruisdante All I did was to run `pip3 install nose`. I didn't do any configuration of any sort. Is there something I should have done first?

Comment: Reading the docs, it doesn't look like it. This may be a more general case of importing one package from another package when they aren't both sub-packages of a common package. Try adding a line in `test.__init__.py` that adds `app` to the python path, ex: `sys.path.append('path_to_app_dir')` and see if that fixes the problem. In the more general case, see discussions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893598/pythonpath-vs-sys-path and various other questions about similar.

Comment: Changing `sys.path` does the job. It feel hacky, though...

Comment: It is hacky. The proper way to do it is to actually install packages as per Antti's answer below so that they're already on your python path. I just wanted a test to confirm that was the problem. This can serve as a short-term fix while you're doing very early stage development so you don't have to write a `setup.py` script.

Comment: You might also want to see the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613439/do-i-need-an-init-py-if-i-want-to-build-a-standalone-program-and-not-a-packa/) that I just answered ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a `setup.py`; in the `setup.py` you should have:

```
setup(
    ...
    scripts = ['bin/run_my_app']
    ...
)
```

and `bin/run_my_app` then a script with content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from app.main import main
main()
```

Now when you run `python setup.py develop` or `python setup.py install`, the `setuptools`/`distribute` will install the command line script `run_my_app` into your path. The `python setup.py develop` makes it possible to *not need to reinstall* the package to virtualenv after each change to the source code; you need to rerun `setup.py develop` only after changes to the `setup.py` itself, or any of the possible C language extension modules in your package.

Alternatively run your main module with

```
python -m app.main
```

Especially do *not* try to run an application from **within** the package with `python app/main`, as it never was supposed to work like that.

---

For developing the code, you'd have a virtualenv, then you can use `python setup.py develop` to link the code into the virtualenv; a special link is installed into the `site-packages` that points to the source code of your application, thus you can develop it in place, but it behaves as if it was installed into the `site-packages`.

Comment: This certainly works for deployment, but it's probably a bit cumbersome to have to re-run `setup.py` every time you make a change to the code.

Comment: That is what setup.py develop is for

Comment: aruisdante [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614269/did-i-organise-my-python-directory-incorrectly/28614578#comment45531991_28614269) that there may be some problem with Nose and the Python path. Do you have any opinions about that?

Comment: nope, nothing wrong with path; you should import the files in tests with fully qualified module names; within the package you should use relative imports (`from . import othermodule`), as this is python 3 (judging from pip3)