# Best practice to package a Python project with cli

Tags: pip, command-line-interface, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I wrote a small app returning routes with my public transport. 
I'd like to package the app and use it via cli like: `$ app_name start destination` which is than handled by the app etc.

I've used the `entry_points` option in `setup.py` by defining an interface file, which is referenced when running the above code from command line.

However, I do not know if that's a best practice to accomplish that (as I have not found it on *python.org*. 
**So: What is a best practice to provide a cli?**

An example I've seen:
with [pytube](https://github.com/nficano/pytube) you can do

```
$ pytube http://youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0 --itag=22
```

[EDIT:] thanks for the comments so far; they hint me to rephrase my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the minimal directory structure to make setuptools work with one\_file.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444747/whats-the-minimal-directory-structure-to-make-setuptools-work-with-one-file-py)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+command+line+script

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/

Comment: https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/

Comment: thanks @phd in my case I had used a similar approach as gehrcke described in his post by defining an interface file and linking a main method via `entry_points` in `setup.py`

however, I haven't see such an approach on python.org why I was wondering what the best practice would be

Comment: `python.org` is devoted to the very CPython, its standard library, docs and the community. What do you expect from them in the area of command line scripts? As for the best practice — there is no one single best. Whatever works for you is ok. And questions about best practices are a bit off-topic at SO.